# change value of this.props.location.state in react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

There are many examples on the Internet that look like the following code:

```
const { state } = this.props.location;
    window.location = state ? state.from.pathname : "/dashboards/index";
```

how can i change this.props.location.state in source class and pass to destination ?

My question is if I want to go from one page (class component) to another using route, how can I change the value of this.props.location.state and pass it to the destination component?
My scenario is that when someone enters a protected page, and redirects to the login page then **returns to the requested page after authentication.** by change value of this.props.location.state?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are asking but as much as I think, you want to add state while pushing to a route. If that's the case, then this should work in `class components`

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/template',
  search: '?query=something',
  state: { key: value }
})
```

And in `functional components` you can use hooks, `useHistory`

```
const { push } = useHistory();

push(path, [state])
```

And you can access the state you just passed in the destination route as 
`in class components`

```
this.props.location.state.key
```

`in functional components`

```
const { state }  = useLocation();

state.key
```

Comment: How do you change the value of this state in the component that sent it? if for instance a functionality depended on the state changing

Comment: @soby the latest react-router-dom has `navigate = useNavigate()` `navigate()` which takes search, state as much as I know. So you can use that, it will update the state directly.

Like: `navigate({state: {} })`

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate this object. You're not supposed to !!

If you want to redirect between pages then you can use:

```
this.props.history.push("/path-to-navigate")
```